# Is there a word that is the antonym of independent?

Tags: probability, statistics

Is there a word that can be substituted for the term "not independent" when referencing an experiment? I am in AP Statistics, and writing "not independent" seems too long. So, is there a widely accepted antonym to independent?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: d...dependent? I suppose it depends :)

Comment: @BennettGardiner Oh you ninja, I just wrote "dependent."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Dependent {}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Well, I probably should have thought through a little more. Thanks anyways.

Comment: At least this is now out there.